# reversed paste in IK mode

Tags: rigging

in the case of arms legs eyes or things like those with symmetric can't be pasted reversed in IK mode?

I mean reversing the LocRot from one arm to another arm

Comment: No idea of your exoerience but you can copy limb/bone animation from one limb to another,  reverse them with SH-M etc. such as legs walking.  Is that what you're trying to do?  More detail if needed.

Comment: Yes I mean that but I fixed the problem just by changing bones' mode

Comment: I think it won't work at all if i dont change bone mode

Comment: I don't move bones in the conventional way.  I use an empty as each limb's handle and then drag the empty. It avoids armature restrictions and quirks.  You've got it going, that's the main thing.